# Equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

A relation $R$ is defined on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ by $(a,b)R(c,d)$ iff $ad = bc$. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I know that in order to find the equivalence relation we need to determine if $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

But I'm having some struggle in understanding this $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Its just the set of natural numbers

Comment: Might be good to specify that (apparently) you intend $0\notin \mathbb N$, or else everything would be related to $(0,0)$. In that case, the equivalence classes are just a copy of the positive rational numbers ($(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}$)

Comment: @rschwieb Good point. If we consider $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, then the relation can still work on $\mathbb{N} \times( \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\})$ though.

Comment: @benguin and then the set of classes is the canonical construction of the rational numbers.

Comment: @benguin Equally effective, although necessitating change in notation :)

Comment: @rschwieb oops, right. thanks.

Comment: @MCUO I don't know if this makes it easier notation wise, but we can also say that the relation $R$ is defined on $\mathbb{N}^2$ by $\vec{x}R\vec{y}$ where $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)$ and $\vec{y} = (y_1,y_2)$ if and only if $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$. So you need to show for all $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \in \mathbb{N}^2$ that (1) $\vec{x}R\vec{x}$ (2) $\vec{x}R\vec{y}$ implies $\vec{y}R\vec{x}$, and (3) if $\vec{x}R\vec{y}$ and $\vec{y}R\vec{z}$, then $\vec{x}R\vec{z}$.

Comment: @rschwieb Or $(\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}) \times \mathbb{N}$ for that strange breed of people that prefer to define $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots \}$ :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers, and $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is the set of **pairs** of natural numbers. So, each element of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is a pair $(n_1, n_2)$ such that $n_1\in\mathbb N$ and $n_2\in\mathbb N$.

---

Your job then, is to show that:

1. $R$ is symmetric, that is, for every pair of natural number pairs $(n_1, n_2)$ and $(m_1, m_2)$, you know that if $(n_1, n_2)R(m_1, m_2)$, then $(m_1, m_2)R(n_1,n_2)$
2. $R$ is reflexive, so for each pair $(n_1, n_2)\in\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$, you know that $(n_1, n_2)R(n_1, n_2)$
3. $R$ is transitive, so for each three pairs $(n_1, n_2), (m_1, m_2), (k_1, k_2)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, you know that if $(n_1, n_2)R(m_1, m_2)$ and $(m_1,m_2)R(k_1, k_2)$, then $(n_1, n_2)R(k_1, k_2)$

---

Sidenote:

Since relations on a set $A$ are *by definition* subsets of the set $A\times A$, this means that your particular relation is, strictly speaking, a subset of $(\mathbb N\times \mathbb N)\times(\mathbb N\times \mathbb N)$

Comment: Might be better to write "pair of natural number pairs" instead of "pair of integer pairs".